# supabase ilike with multiple reference table

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

Is it possible to do filters `or` with multiple reference tables, like if we do it in raw postgresql query like below (just for example):

```
SELECT reports.*, report_categories.*, report_details.* FROM reports
LEFT JOIN report_categories on report_categories.id = reports.report_category_id
LEFT JOIN report_details on report_details.id = reports.report_detail
LEFT JOIN listings on listings.id = reports.listing_id
WHERE reports.ticket_no ILIKE '%somthing%' or listings.title ILIKE '%somthing%';
```

I Tried to achieved it using supabase, but always get below.

```
{
    "reportData": null,
    "error": {
        "code": "42703",
        "details": null,
        "hint": null,
        "message": "column reports.title does not exist"
    }
}
```

Here my code;

```
async function getReport(req) {
const { page, limit, search, type, sort, status } = req.query;

let query = supabase
  .from(tables.REPORTS)
  .select(
    `*,
report_category:report_category_id(id, title, type),
buyer:buyer_id(id, display_name, profile_picture), 
listing:listing_id(id, title, photos, thumbnails, store(id, display_name, profile_picture, toco_name, toco_profile_picture, toco_short_name)), 
store:store_id(id, display_name, profile_picture, toco_name, toco_profile_picture, toco_short_name)`,
    { count: "exact" }
  )
  .is("deleted_at", null);

if (status) {
  const splittedStatus = status.split(",");
  query = query.in("status", splittedStatus);
}

// ***** this line what I'm trying to achieve *****

if (search) {
  query = query.or(`ticket_no.ilike.'%${search}%',title.ilike.'%${search}%',toco_name.ilike.'%${search}%'`);
}

// *****************************

const limitInt = Number(limit) || 10;
const offset = (Number(page) - 1) * limitInt || 0;
const currentPage = Number(page) || 1;

query = query.order("created_at", {
  ascending: sort === "asc" ? true : false,
});

query = query.range(offset, offset + limitInt - 1);

const { data: reportData, error, count } = await query;

return reportData
```

Please anyone help me, I've been trying to achieve for many days, but no results. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The code below isn't tested, but you should be able to specify the columns by appending the table name in front of it like `listing.title.ilike`. Not sure which table `toco_name` belongs to, but if it's not on the reports table, then you would need to add the table name there too.

```js
if (search) {
  query = query.or(`ticket_no.ilike.'%${search}%', listing.title.ilike.'%${search}%',toco_name.ilike.'%${search}%'`);
}
```